# Migrating my Blogger site to CraftCMS

Tags: migration, import

Has anyone migrated a Blogger site to CraftCMS? I'd like to migrate comments and posts. What is the best way to go about this? Could I import my site to Wordpress and then to Craft?

Answer (score 4):

I migrated a Blogger site by writing a Craft plugin to parse Blogger's XML and save images, posts, and categories into the Craft setup established with the client. The challenge with Craft is that last part: *you're* the one deciding how things will work, the CMS doesn't come with opinions about how your blog posts will be constructed or organized.

You can use the [Feed Me](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me) or [Sprout Import](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/import) plugins to migrate your Blogger data, but you'll still need to set up your blog in Craft and decide how to map the Blogger data to your Craft install.

Comments are another animal. It may be easiest to move them to [Disqus](https://disqus.com/). I've not used [this comment plugin](https://github.com/verbb/comments), but expect it would be solid.

Comment: Agree 100%. Having migrated a WordPress blog to Craft, I also found that the difficult bit was structuring the blog in Craft and deciding how to map the data in.